# woocommerce taxonomies ajax filter, get the correct pagination

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, post, woocommerce

I am building a woocommerce taxonomies ajax filter, everything is fine except one problem. 
When I replace the product list with the filtered one, The pagination don't get updated to match the new result. This makes sense because after I filter the post I am only calling

```
 wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
```

so my question is: 
How do I replace / update the pagination.

This is my code:

```
    public function hmuAjaxCall()
{
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php

        $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];

        if (!wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'ajax-nonce')) {
            die('Busted!');
        }
        $cpt = 'product';
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $cpt,
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'paged' =>  $paged,
            'orderby' => array(
                'ID' => 'DESC',
            ),

        );

        if ($_POST['args'] == 'true') {
            $result = array();
            foreach ($_POST['attributes'] as $tax => $term) {
                $result [] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => $tax,
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array($term),

                );
            }
            //var_dump($result);
            $args['tax_query'] = array(
                'relation' => 'AND',

                $result
            );

        }


        /* when using namespace dont forget to add \ to WP_Query */
        $query = new \WP_Query($args);
        if ($query->have_posts()) :
            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                $query->the_post();

                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

            }

            wp_reset_postdata();
        else :
            echo '<h2> No Result found</h2>';
        endif;

        die();

        ?>
    </div>

    <?php
}
```

and this is my js code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: adminAjax ,
        data : {
            action : 'customfilter',
            nonce: nonce,
            attributes: href,
            args : arg,

        },
        type:'POST', // POST
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            $('body').addClass('load-ajax');
        },
        error:function (data) {
            $('body').removeClass('load-ajax');
            console.log('ERROR');
        },
        success:function(data){
            $('body').removeClass('load-ajax');
            if(data =='') {
                console.log('empty');
            }else {

                $('#con').empty().html(data);
            }


            // $('#lazyload').empty();
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:**

I managed to get the right pagination by adding this after the loop:

```
 <nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
                <?php
                echo paginate_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pagination_args', array(
                    'base'         => esc_url_raw( str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', remove_query_arg( 'add-to-cart', get_pagenum_link( 999999999, false ) ) ) ),
                    'format'       => '',
                    'add_args'     => false,
                    'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                    'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
                    'prev_text'    => '&larr;',
                    'next_text'    => '&rarr;',
                    'type'         => 'list',
                    'end_size'     => 3,
                    'mid_size'     => 3,
                ) ) );
                ?>
            </nav>
```

But when clicking on the page I am getting this link:
/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?paged=2
so the question now how to get the right link?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i managed to fix it:

getting the nav result within the loop and hide it

```
 <nav class="woocommerce-pagination" id="hmuPagination" style="display: none">
                <?php
                echo paginate_links(array(
                    'base' => home_url('/%_%'),
                    'format' => '&paged=%#%',
                    'add_args' => false,
                    'current' => $paged,
                    'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
                    'prev_text' => '&larr;',
                    'next_text' => '&rarr;',
                    'type' => 'list',
                    'end_size' => 3,
                    'mid_size' => 3,
                ));
                ?>
            </nav>
```

then in the js file I replace the pagination with the ajaxed one:

```
 $('.woocommerce-pagination').replaceWith($(data).find('#hmuPagination').show());
  $('.woocommerce-result-count').replaceWith($(data).find('#hmuCount').show());
```